# Angular 2 components polymorphism

Tags: angular, polymorphism

I would like to implement a component acting like a container with dynamically added children components. The type and number of children components should be configured on server side.

So Models arrived `from` the server could look like this:

```
export class ModelBase {
    public data: any;
}

export class ModelA extends ModelBase {
    public dataA: any;
}

export class ModelB extends ModelBase {    
    public dataB: any
}
```

Simplified components could be like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "component-base"
})
export class BaseComponent {
  @Input() model: ModelBase;
}

@Component({
  selector: "component-a",
  template: "<div>component-a</div>"
})
export class AComponent extends BaseComponent {
  @Input() model: ModelBase;
}

@Component({
  selector: "component-b",
  template: "<div>component-b</div>"
})
export class BComponent extends BaseComponent {
  @Input() model: ModelBase;
}
```

And here is the Application and how I would like to work with my components:

```
@Component({
        selector: 'app',
        template: `
          <div *ngFor="#model of models">
              <component-base [model]="model"></component-base>
          </div>
        `
})
export class App {
}
```

I want `component-base` will be replaced with the concrete implementation based on `model` type. For example, with component-a.
Does workflow like this is possible to implement with Angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better API for this functionality coming: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/11235.

In the meantime, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/36325468/5307109. You'll likely have to modify it so that you can pass data through it to your destination component and call a custom component hook on load.

Using the wrapper described above, your `ComponentBase` will have a template of its own and inject each model's associated component into the wrapper.

```
export class ModelA extends ModelBase {
  dataA: any;
  component: any = AComponent;
}

@Component({
  selector: "component-base",
  template: `
    <dcl-wrapper [type]="model.component" [init-data]="model"></dcl-wrapper>
  `
})
export class BaseComponent {
  @Input() model: ModelBase;
}

@Component({
  selector: "component-a",
  template: "<div>component-a</div>"
})
export class AComponent {
  @Input() model: ModelBase;

  /**
   * Custom hook you might create in DclWrapper.
   */
  onDclInit(model: ModelBase) : void {
    this.model = model;
  }

}
```